# Create new line with react tsx not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, line-breaks

I want to set the username on a new line in my React tsx (TypeScript) web application.

`entry.comment` contains the following string: **jsdkjfdjsfds**
`entry.username` contains the following string: **Noah**

My code looks like this, I tried with `\n` but this isn't working:

```html
<div className={classes.entryContent}>
  <Typography className={classes.entryContentParagraph} variant="body2" paragraph={true}>
    <ReactMarkdown>
      {entry.comment + "\n" + entry.username}
    </ReactMarkdown>
  </Typography>
</div>
```

[image: Picture with the not working line break]

Do you have an advice? Stay fresh!

Comment: Not sure, but I think ask to upvote is not allowed here, or, at least, it is not recommended :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this issue and to markdown conversions

https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown/issues/273

You should put two spaces at the end of the line you want to break, basically, something like:

```
line one  \nline two
```

This

[image]

will give you

[image]

but this

[image]

will give you

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, do you know how I can write single words bold in my example? @Emanuele Scarabattoli

Comment: Sure, https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#bold so, **bold** (wrapped with **)

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enough reputation I have to add it in an answer.

I haven't worked with this library before but can you try adding the break-line tag, like `<br />`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but this doesn't work in the brackets, it only works in html code, got the solution by Emanuele down here. But thanks for your help I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className={classes.entryContent}>
  <Typography className={classes.entryContentParagraph} variant="body2" paragraph={true}>
    <ReactMarkdown>
      <p>{entry.comment}</p>
      <p>{entry.username}</p>
    </ReactMarkdown>
  </Typography>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice but this doesnt work because `ReactMarkdown` in my case only accepts one single argument. Got the solution by Emanuele at the bottom.